# qTip2 - refresh tooltip while it is active

Tags: javascript, jquery, qtip2

I'm using qTip2 here, and need the ability to refresh the content of the tooltip while it is still active.  The elements with the tooltip have a click event that does some calculations that can change what I want to be displayed in the tooltip.

I have tried calling the 'destroy' method and rebinding the qtip2 after each recalculation, and it works but only after moving the mouse away and bringing it back.

What I want to achieve is to force the currently active tooltip to redraw itself.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you look in the [documentation](http://craigsworks.com/projects/qtip2/docs/api/#methods), there is a "set" method to change the content:

```
$('.selector').qtip('option', 'content.text', 'new content'); // Preferred
```

Is that what you're looking for?

---

Update: After testing out the api options, they seem to not be working properly, but I've found another method - here is a [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Mottie/EEwwg/418/) - hover over the tip for 1 sec to see it change.

```
// make sure you target a specific tip
var qapi = $('#tip1').data('qtip'),
    newtip = 'new tooltip content'
qapi.options.content.text = newtip; // update content stored in options
qapi.elements.content.text(newtip); // update visible tooltip content
qapi.redraw(); // redraw to adjust tooltip borders
```

Comment: It sounds like he wants to change the content of the tooltip _while_ the tip is still open.

Comment: @Sparky672: Yeah I knew that's what andrew wanted, but after testing it, it doesn't seem to work =(

Comment: Actually the top method does work... it wasn't working for me when I used `$(this)` inside of the setTimeout in the demo (DUH) instead of `$('.selector')` so that's why I worked on the alternate method. Either way works, but the first would be the best.